# Problem with calculating eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Solution: The eigenvalues for $\begin{bmatrix}1.25 & -.75 \\ -.75 & 1.25\end{bmatrix}$ are $2$ and $0.5$.

I'm confused on how it's not $1$ and $-1$. If we set up the characteristic matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}5/4 - \lambda & -3/4 \\ -3/4 & 5/4 - \lambda \end{bmatrix}$

$ad-bc=0$

$25/16 - \lambda ^2 - 9/16 = 0$

$16/16- \lambda ^2=0$

$\lambda = 1, -1$

Comment: Missing some terms in your characteristic polynomial. Should be $\lambda ^2-2.5 \lambda +1.$

Comment: You made an error in calculating the polynomial. It should be $(\frac{5}{4}-\lambda)^2-(-\frac{3}{4})^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\frac{5}{4}-\lambda)^2-\frac{9}{16}=0$$

Assuming you got the above equation correctly, your expansion of the terms was incorrect.

$$\frac{25}{16}-\frac{5}{2}\lambda+\lambda^2-\frac{9}{16}=0$$

$$\lambda^2-\frac{5}{2}\lambda+1=0$$

$$(\lambda-\frac{5}{4})^2+\frac{-25+16}{16}=0$$

$$\lambda = \frac{5\pm 3}{4}\implies \lambda =\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{or}\quad\lambda=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Third last line should read $$\frac{25}{16}-\frac{5}{2}\lambda+\lambda^2-\frac{9}{16}=0$$
It looks like you just forgot to expand the bracket $\left(\frac{5}{4}-\lambda\right)^2$ properly using binomial expansion.